# How to add a new level to section level?

Tags: sectioning

I have an article with the multi-level of section. I define new command \tenbai with the level \section. I want to add the extra level A, B, C... such as A. Lý thuyết, B.Bài tập .... and named its level \phan and put that level after \tenbai and before \section. How can I do that? Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
    \par
    \stepcounter{sobai}%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
        \hline \hline
        \hfill\bfseries\huge\strut \S\thesobai. #1\hfill\mbox{} \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}%
    \par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
    \tenbai{Số phức}
    \section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}
\section{Số phức liên hợp - Môđun của số phức}
\section{Phép chia cho số phức khác 0}
\section{Phép cộng, trừ và nhân hai số phức}
\end{document}
```

I want to

```
\begin{document}
        \tenbai{Số phức}
\phan{Lý thuyết}
        \section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}
    \section{Số phức liên hợp - Môđun của số phức}
    \section{Phép chia cho số phức khác 0}
    \section{Phép cộng, trừ và nhân hai số phức}
\phan{Bài tập}
\section{Bài tập 1}
....
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please try to clarify the desired output? You already specified, what `\phan` sholud look like, but what about the sections? Should they stay numbered as 1, 2, ...or should they be numbered A.1, A.2,... Should the numbering be reset once you reach the second \phan command...? Also, why not sompla modify the alredy existing sectioning commands instead of defining new ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `\phan` be exactly like `\section`, and `\section` be exactly like `\subsection`. Then, a slight adjustment in the representations of the counters provides what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{sobai}%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
    \hline \hline
    \hfill\bfseries\huge\strut \S\thesobai. #1\hfill\mbox{} \\
    \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}%
  \par\nobreak
}
\let\phan\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\subsection}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\tenbai{Số phức}

\phan{Lý thuyết}

\section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}
\section{Số phức liên hợp - Môđun của số phức}
\section{Phép chia cho số phức khác 0}
\section{Phép cộng, trừ và nhân hai số phức}

\phan{Bài tập}

\section{Bài tập 1}

\end{document}
```